# Как будет на английском слово "вёрстка"?

Tags: вёрстка, терминология

Помогите, пожалуйста, перевести на английский слово "вёрстка"

Comment: Контекст ?

Comment: извините за немного неуместный вопрос, но как комменты минусовать?

Comment: Сейчас комментарии не минусуются, в будущем для них будет тревога.

Comment: только что здесь был комментарий с рейтингом ``-1``, тов. @alexlz, не подумайте, что это про ваш коммент

Comment: Можно, наверное, преобразовать комментарий в ответ, заминусовать его, а потом снова сделать комментарием.

*Видимо как-то так (иного алгоритма не вижу).*

@Spectre, хотите на Вашем комментарии попробуем ? На своем не получится, т.к. минусовать/плюсовать свои ответы нельзя.

Comment: хитро, однако, но наверно вы правы

Comment: @avp а может автор коммента его сам удалил, не приходило в голову?

> Можно, наверное, преобразовать
> комментарий в ответ, заминусовать его,
> а потом снова сделать комментарием.

Среди известных мне людей которые имеют право делать ответы комментариями и наоборот - нет **дыбилов** которые страдают подобным!

Если у комментария стоит отрецательный голос, значит этот коммент был ранее ответом получивший -1, потом уже преобразован в комментарий за отсутсвия логики или несоответствия ответу как таковому!

Comment: Это очевидно, просто продемонстрировал **возможный** алгоритм. 

То, что мне 

    "не приходило в голову"

даже начал описывать, а потом передумал (т.к. тривиально).

Comment: ППЦ, ну и вопросики пошли...

Comment: эм, http://translate.google.com.ua/#ru/en/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0 :)

Comment: @Francesco: этому вопросу скоро год :) Когда его задали, нас с вами ещё не было на этом сайте.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта.

Answer (score 9):

1. В контексте HTML верстки - переводится как HTML coding
2. В полиграфическом контексте - означает makeup или markup

Comment: **makeup** это как бы дословно

**coding in html** а это типа дополнения что имеется ввиду верстка в HTML

Answer (score 4):

layout, coding

Answer (score 3):

(*Займусь-ка и я некромантией*)

Никто ещё не упомянул **typesetting**.

В защиту этого перевода скажу, что википедия [Typesetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typesetting) на английском связывает с [Вёрсткой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) на русском. (В обратную сторону тоже.)

Comment: не, ну это тоже книжное. Вроде переводится как "набор".

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev: Так и есть, это полиграфический термин. А почему "не"?

Answer (score 1):

Если в отношении веб, то **markup**

Comment: markup -- это вроде "разметка".

Answer (score 1):

Layout. Просто зайдите на зарубежный фриланс сайт, и посмотрите в перечне разделов верстку, в основном она там называется layouts.

Answer (score 0):

[makeup, page-proofs](http://translate.google.ru/#ru/en/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: page-proofs подходит к книгам, журналам, короче к печати. но походу не к вебсайтам.

Comment: @Jeremen1: ТС не упомянул контекст, так что нам приходится лишь догадываться.

Comment: @VladD, да не подумал. Но всё же я думаю он хотел бы узнать на счет верстки веб сайтов. Так как в инете найти перевод с русского на английский не составляет труда:)

Comment: @Jeremen1: Ох, знали бы вы, сколько вопросов, на которые в гугле ответ находится без труда, задают на этом сайте!

Comment: @VladD не спорю, но у тебя такой же вопрос вставал, так что погуглить несколько дольше пришлось чем я ожидал...

Answer (score 0):

Мой заказчик из Нидерландов называет HTML верстальщика - slicer

Answer (score 0):

Я использую markup, ибо: HTML- HyperText Markup Language — язык гипертекстовой разметки

Часто встречаю 'mark' и 'marking'.

А вообще:
http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0/ru-en/LingvoComputer/#lingvo/

И с этим скорее-всего сюда: http://english.sezn.ru/

Answer (score -1):

Front-end developing